# Access microphone for android devices in c#

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, voice-recording

sorry if this has been answered somewhere, i haven't been able to find what i need so far.

I need to access the microphone on android devices in c# to record and playback voice.

How do i go about doing this? If anyone could provide examples that would be very useful as i am a beginner. I am using monodevelop to create the application. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C# on Android I'm guessing that you mean Xamarin(?).

The Xamarin website has a [Working with audio](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/working_with_audio) page with information on how to use the various audio APIs (e.g. MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder) from your app, including some example code.